# Installing an ArcGIS add-in on several PCs

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I usually do my python scripts and add them to ArcMap in the form of add-ins.

First I launch the ArcGIS Python Add-In Wizard, create a project, a toolbar and the tool.

Then, every time I do an update I re-run the makeaddin.py and re-install the addin.esriaddin.

Now, I would like to install this tool in other PCs and I don't have experience with that.

Do I have to go one by one and do the same as above every time? what if I update the script, how do I update it in the other machines?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You can also deploy addins by copying the .esriaddin file to a network location and [telling the addin manager](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/guide-books/python-addins/sharing-and-installing-add-ins.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_430DD0FE0725426D9A977EF8BB39C5C6) to search this folder.

This location can be added to every PC in your organisation using group policy to set a registry key. See the last section of [this page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Advanced_add_in_concepts/0001000004n7000000/) for more details.

Comment: Apparently, one of the libraries (the cx_Oracle one) which I use in my addin, is missing in the other PCs' python installations (import cx_Oracle fails), so not everything is contained in the addin.esriaddin. Am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure about python addins - I've been using C#. I know that when you distribute a python module with setuptools, you can add a requirements.txt that lists all the required modules. Maybe Esri has a similar feature?

Answer (score 5):

If you already packed your addin to an `.esriaddin`-file (which is nothing but an archive-file similar to ZIP or others) all you have to do is copy the file to your client-PC and install it by double-clicking.